# Create a new column in my SQL View - Column must be two other columns combined

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

I am trying to create a new view, but I also want this view to have a new column. The new column must be StkCode and Description_1 combined.

For example: If my StkCode is DX11122 and Description_1 is Vanilla Powder; I want a field that will read as follows: "Vanilla Powder - DX11122"

```
CREATE VIEW KFF_Rep_Comm
AS
SELECT vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.AccName AS AccountName
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.Account AS AccountNum
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.RepID
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.RepName
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.CommPerc AS CommPercent
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.Credit
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.Debit
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.MUPercent AS MarkUpPercent
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.ProfitPercent AS GrossProfitPercent
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.SgdTrxAmt AS InvValue
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.SgdCost AS Cost
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.SgdProfit AS GrossProfit
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.SgdQty AS QtySold_Kg
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.TxDate
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.TrCodeID
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.StkCode
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.RepCode
,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.Reference
,Client.DCLink
,StkItem.StockLink
FROM Client
INNER JOIN vw_KLX_RepCommTrx
ON vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.AccName = Client.Name
INNER JOIN StkItem
ON StkItem.Code = vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.StkCode
ADD ItemAndCode VARCHAR
Update vw_KLX_RepCommTrx 
SET ItemAndCode Concat(StkCode, ' - ',Description_1) ---HERE is where I am going wrong, I think?
```

Comment: **Just to add** I will need some form of trigger to make sure it keeps updating

Comment: How does the Add and update belong to the view definition, and why do you think you need a trigger to keep the view updated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need to add another column to your select:

```
CREATE VIEW KFF_Rep_Comm
AS
SELECT vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.AccName AS AccountName
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.Account AS AccountNum
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.RepID
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.RepName
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.CommPerc AS CommPercent
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.Credit
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.Debit
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.MUPercent AS MarkUpPercent
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.ProfitPercent AS GrossProfitPercent
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.SgdTrxAmt AS InvValue
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.SgdCost AS Cost
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.SgdProfit AS GrossProfit
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.SgdQty AS QtySold_Kg
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.TxDate
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.TrCodeID
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.StkCode
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.RepCode
    ,vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.Reference
    ,Client.DCLink
    ,StkItem.StockLink
    ,Concat(vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.StkCode, ' - ',vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.Description_1) as ItemAndCode 
FROM Client
    INNER JOIN vw_KLX_RepCommTrx
        ON vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.AccName = Client.Name
    INNER JOIN StkItem
        ON StkItem.Code = vw_KLX_RepCommTrx.StkCode
```

It is not clear from your code where does column `Description_1` come from, but I assume it is the same view `vw_KLX_RepCommTrx`. If not - you can update it with the actual table/view name (or remove table/view name if column name is unique)